# php: can i zip glob files without full path?

Tags: php, zip, glob

this code works like a magic batch of fresh potato chips on a really bad day: PURE JOY.  but when i extract the archive, the files are nested in the path they were stored in on the server.  me no likey.  how do i zip the glob without the full path; just the files.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("_dox/pdftmp/".$_SESSION['archiveName'], ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files_pdf = glob('_dox/pdftmp/*.pdf');
foreach ($files_pdf as $file)
{
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

remember: just files, no extra folders.

WR!

Answer (score 7):

Specify the "local name" that the files will have inside the zip. See the [`addFile()`](http://php.net/ziparchive.addfile) docs.

```
$zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
```